# Use createPortal to launch component instance in new window?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to open a new window that effectively launches a second (third etc.) instance of a core app component upon button click. It seems that React.createPortal might be a great start, so I went off of some tutorials that use it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function handleClick(name) {
  render(
    <MyPortal>
      <AppInterface type={name} />
    </MyPortal>
  )
}

const MyPortal = (props) => {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  var win = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');
  win.document.body.appendChild(container);
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children, container);
}
```

So far to no avail:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you!